# What is the type of this chart?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am working on Microsoft Power BI to implement an analytics dashboard. I stumbled upon one of the dashboards that has an informative chart. I would like to know the type/name of chart. Could you please share with me the type of this chart?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This chart is called **butterfly chart.**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help in this regard.